# Bulk geometry ES query

Tags: elasticsearch, bulk, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I currently have an ES query to find the nearest location to a lat/long:

```
GET /geo/_search
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "_geo_distance": {
                "geometry": {
                    "lat": 64,
                    "lon": 34
                },
                "order": "asc",
                "unit": "mi",
                "distance_type": "plane"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 1
}
```

I want to be able to run this in 1 query for multiple lat/longs, which would return each lat/long related to their nearest location. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /geo/_search
{
"sort": [
    {
        "_geo_distance": {
            "geometry": [
                {
                    "lat": 64,
                    "lon": 34
                },
                {
                    "lat": 0,
                    "lon": 0
                }
            ],
            "order": "asc",
            "unit": "mi",
            "distance_type": "plane"
        }
    }
],
"size": 1
}
```

This answer gives more than one point per geo_point. I don't think you can retrieve only the top one per geo_point in one query. You might need to filter the results or to use a loop per each geo_point